# How to perform Regex on listjs hackerlist?

Tags: javascript, regex, listjs

I would like to perform regex on a search functionality of List.js. How it works by default is that it searches for a word which exists in a whole sentence. What I want to achieve is that it should search a word which is the start of a sentence.

[image]

In above picture, you see "Was" exists in all 4 sentences but I only want it to short list where "Was" is the first word of each sentence.

[ListJs Source](http://www.listjs.com/)

Comment: you might try something like this `(?:^|[!?\.])\s*Was`, where you either match the beginning of a line or punctuation mark, followed by optional spaces and your keyword

Comment: I think you might want to write your own plugin for it...

Comment: [*`options.sortFunction` is used if you want to make your own sort function.*](http://www.listjs.com/docs/list-api#sort). I guess the correct way is to write this function (perhaps, by taking [this default one](https://github.com/javve/natural-sort/blob/master/index.js) and writing yours based on it) and pass it to the sorting method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for suggestions. For now I have done a workaround by modifying the core list.js file. I replaced:

```
var search = {
    list: function() {
        for (var k = 0, kl = list.items.length; k < kl; k++) {
            search.item(list.items[k]);
        }
    },
    item: function(item) {
        item.found = false;
        for (var j = 0, jl = columns.length; j < jl; j++) {
            if (search.values(item.values(), columns[j])) {
                item.found = true;
                return;
            }
        }
    },
    values: function(values, column) {
        if (values.hasOwnProperty(column)) {
            text = toString(values[column]).toLowerCase();
            if ((searchString !== "") && (text.search(searchString) > -1)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    },
    reset: function() {
        list.reset.search();
        list.searched = false;
    }
};
```

With

```
if (typeof String.prototype.startsWith != 'function') {
    // see below for better implementation!
    String.prototype.startsWith = function (str) {
        return this.indexOf(str) === 0;
    };
}
var search = {
    list: function() {
        for (var k = 0, kl = list.items.length; k < kl; k++) {
            search.item(list.items[k]);
        }
    },
    item: function(item) {
        item.found = false;
        for (var j = 0, jl = columns.length; j < jl; j++) {
            if (search.values(item.values(), columns[j])) {
                item.found = true;
                return;
            }
        }
    },
    values: function(values, column) {
        if (values.hasOwnProperty(column)) {
            text = toString(values[column]).toLowerCase();
            if ((searchString !== "") && (text.startsWith(searchString))) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    },
    reset: function() {
        list.reset.search();
        list.searched = false;
    }
};
```

**Explanation:**
I created **startsWith** function (found on stackoverflow) which checks whether the search string starts with the exact characters of a given sentence, and modified the **values** function of parent **search** block. and replaced its text.search() function with my startsWith function.